# Get the app icon as int identifier

Tags: android

I want to retrieve the icon of an app. If I use

```
String pkg = "com.app.my";
Drawable icon = getContext().getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(pkg);
```

The result is a Drawable. how can I retrieve the id of the associated resource for passing it as extra in an intent? THanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following snippet should do the trick.

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
String pkg = "com.app.my";

try {
    ApplicationInfo ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(pkg, 0);
    int iconId = ai.icon;
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
             s=name of the drawable
             int id=getResources().getIdentifier(s,"drawable",getPackageName());

            you will get the id here
```

Comment: Thanks but i dont know the name of the drawable :P

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
getResources().getIdentifier() from your Context (e.g., Activity)
```

Comment: THanks but i dont know the name of the drawable :P

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the icon of an other app, or the app you're in?

If it's in the app you're in, then this should be sufficient right?

```
    int i = R.drawable.icon;
```