# Resource ID of drawable

Tags: android, drawable

I was able to get the list of installed application's name in a listview but I'm having problem adding their icons. I have created a new xml layout and included an imageview.

I'm using the following to retrieve the icons

```
appInfo.icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
```

To load the application info I was using a

```
HashMap<String,String>.
```

It is my understanding that I could use a

```
HashMap<String,Integer>
```

then just send the drawable Resource ID to the Imageview and it would work.

How can I get the Resource Id of a drawable object?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8547313/752320) shows how to get the icon for a given package name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting a int of a drawable in your app:

```
int yourInt = getResources().getIdentifier(fileName, "drawable", getPackageName());
```

Getting an icon from another app:

[Android - How to get an icon of an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612233/android-how-to-get-an-icon-of-an-app)

Comment: How do I get fileName of the Icon?

Comment: Oh sorry misread your question, Ill update my answer later since you want icon of other app.

Comment: not what I was asking but led to a link that solved it by using      pm.getApplicationInfo(pkg, 0);